# Ignoring requests with route constraints

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've couple of routes defined in `Global.asax.cs`

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Custom",
        "party/get/{a}~{b}",          
        new { controller = "party", action = "get" },
        new { a = @"\d+", b = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Party", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If the request is `http://localhost:58684/party/get/37~12` then it will be matched by the first route and the values of `a` and `b` are `37` and `12` respectively.

If the request is `http://localhost:58684/party/get/37~-12` then the first route don't matches this request since `-12` not matches the constraint `@"\d+"` and the default route matches the request (**I don't want this behavior**).

**If a request is not matched by one route due to some constraint how can I avoid the other following routes matching the request? I'm not interested to set any constraint for the following routes.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use routes.IgnoreRoute.

one example:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the routing engine to "ignore a route if it matches part of this route but not all of it". You can, however, add another route to catch the bad requests and do something else with them - display an error page or redirect to another action.

If you add this directly after your desired route it should catch the unwanted requests.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "BadPartyValue",
    "party/get/{badValue}",          
    new { controller = "party", action = "BadValue" }
);
```